# jQuery Draggable restrict drag on Y axis for 100 pixels before unrestricting

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I am editing a Tower of Hanoi game, where a user can drag discs from one peg to another peg.

[image: Tower of Hanoi]

The [plugin I found](https://github.com/gedex/TowerOfHanoiJS) is using jQuery UI draggable/dropable to accomplish this.  I want to edit the plugin to implement functionality where the user has to first drag up (Y axis) a certain number of pixels before they are then able to drag left/right/up/down without any constraints.

**Is there any way to require the user to first drag up 100 pixels before allowing the user to drag anywhere within the container?**

Below is the code where I bind the draggable functionality to the disc (as well as record the coordinates of thr drag into local storage), in case it helps.

```
discObj.getDisc().draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    containment: this.container,
    cursor: 'move',
    disabled: true,
    helper: 'clone',
    scroll: false,
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        var pos = ui.position;
        var numPos = localStorage.getItem('numStepPositions');
        var coordinates = 'disc:' + discID + ';left:' + pos.left + ';top:' + pos.top +';';

        localStorage.setItem('position' + numPos, coordinates);

        numPos++;
        localStorage.setItem('numStepPositions', numPos);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit `axis` parameter after having detected a negative Y translation :

```
$(".box").draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    cursor: 'move',
    //disabled: true,
    helper: 'clone',
    axis: "y",
    scroll: false,
    start: function (event, ui) {
        initialPos = ui.position.top;
        $(this).addClass("Yaxis");
    },
    drag: function (event, ui) {
        var pos = ui.position;
        if (pos.top < initialPos - 100 && $(this).is(".Yaxis")) {
            $(this).removeClass("Yaxis");
            $(this).draggable('option', 'axis', false);
        }

    },
    stop: function( event, ui ) {
     $(this).draggable('option', 'axis', "y");
    }
});
```

Please see [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhsbsxrp/)

---

First add `axis: "y"` to the `.draggable()` options. Then, you have to store the initial top position of the dragged element at drop start, and add a flag that tells it is axis constrained :

```
start: function (event, ui) {
    initialPos = ui.position.top;
    $(this).addClass("Yaxis");
},
```

Now, just check in `drag` event if the dragged element have been mover over 100px, and have Yaxis classname :

```
var pos = ui.position;
if (pos.top < initialPos - 100 && $(this).is(".Yaxis")) {
    $(this).removeClass("Yaxis");
    $(this).draggable('option', 'axis', false);
}
```

And finally reset `axis:"y"` at drag stop :

```
stop: function( event, ui ) {
     $(this).draggable('option', 'axis', "y");
}
```

Comment: You, sir, are a gentleman and a scholar!  Thanks for the quick answer.  I just implemented your edit it into the actual game and it works as expected.  Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure, glad that helped :)

Comment: Your revisions helped.  At first, I tried it and realized I forgot a small bit of the edit.  Setting each edit apart really helped.